# Suggested edits with a part of the post as a comment

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Today I faced two edit suggestions which had a part of the post as a comment. Such edits don't harm and contain real improvements.

What shall I do with such edits? And how to notify their author about purposes of the Comment field?

Example: [TGA File Header is not correct on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17123165)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit summaries have value, they are required for suggested edits

In addition to being communication to reviewers, they are communication to the posts author. Edit summaries are a *required* field for edits made by users with <2k. While they *can* be left blank once you obtain [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), they should still be used, in most cases.

Communicating to the author *why* the post is being edited is important. Doing so can serve many purposes, not the least is to let the author know why something is better the way it's been edited into. Post authors are notified when their post is edited. Most will care enough about their post to find out what was changed. Having some explanation in the edit summary helps them understand whats going on. Some of those authors will look at the edits and learn from them. For those, explaining the edit can help the author make their future posts better.

Basically, if Stack Exchange didn't feel the edit summary was important, it wouldn't be required for <2k edits. Yes, it's not *required* for a edits once you have >2k rep. By then, you are expected to know when an edit summary should be used, and when you can dispense with providing one.

What to do about a review with a bad edit summary depends on the circumstances. For the specific example, I'd probably ignore the edit summary. It looks like it *might* be a cut-and-paste failure. I would, thus, assume good faith and just let it slide.

If it was a pattern of bad edit summaries, I would: Leave a comment explaining to the editor that edit summaries have value both to getting the edit approved and to communicate to the author and people looking at the edit history page. If the pattern continued after the user received the comment, I have been known to start rejecting their edits with bad summaries. Doing this takes considerably more effort, because I feel that I should edit the post to apply any appropriate changes rather than leave a post in poor condition. Thus, I would generally choose the "reject and edit" option, if I was at the point of rejecting their edits due to bad edit summaries. Again, only if there was an uncorrected pattern of providing bad edit summaries.

By bad edit summary, I usually mean where it's clear the user is not even trying to provide a minimal summary, or where they are clearly actively avoiding providing one.

### Code Changed: The [example review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17123165) should have been rejected and edited

I would have **rejected and edited** the specific example review you link in the question, because:

- **Changed code**: The edit changed the text "colourmaporigin" to "colormap-origin". Even a basic reading of the post indicates that "colourmaporigin" is actually code. It should have been placed in code format: `colourmaporigin`. Specifically, it is defined in the `struct` in the first code block as:

  ```
    WORD colourmaporigin
  ```

  Thus, it absolutely should not have been changed to "colormap-origin".

  I have edited the post to correct this code back to the original and place it in code formatting.

  Note: Changing "colour" to "color" would be bad in itself, even if not in code. Edits should not be changing from one valid English spelling to another, just because it's the editor's preference. But, this is code, so it certainly should not be changed to being something wrong.

In this case, the bad edit summary is clearly secondary.

While I tend to ignore a bad edit summary in an otherwise substantial, obviously good edit, unless I happen to have seen that bad edit summaries are a pattern for this user, I'm not willing to ignore the significantly incorrect change to code (even though the code was not already in code format).

Thus, I would **reject and edit**. My edit would have been to:

- Change colourmaporigin to `colourmaporigin`
- Correct the spelling issues and minor grammar change identified by the editor
- Correct additional grammar issues. While incorrect, it wasn't causing the post to be misunderstood.

Frankly, I feel that the reviewer who approved this edit failed in their job as a reviewer. There are very few changes in this edit, so the issue wasn't buried in a  bunch of noise. The change from "colourmaporigin" to "colormap-origin" is sufficiently unusual, even in gross-form, such that it should have triggered an aware reviewer to take a closer look at what was really happening. From there, reading the sentence should have indicated that it was talking about code. Even just using pattern-matching, it should be clear that it's something from the code, which should have made reviewers either reject the edit or skip the review due to a lack of domain knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Judge the edit on its own merit.

The particular example you linked looks OK, the only issue here is that there is no relevant Edit Summary. This is only an issue for the reviewers and the OP. It does not affect the edit itself; if the edit gets Approved, the visitors won't see the Edit Summary. Only those inspecting the edit history will.

If an edit is Approved, you can @-comment the editor. Then you can explain to them that they should provide a relevant Edit Summary. You could point out that it is in their own interest, as a proper Edit Summary helps the reviewer understand the edit, making them more likely to Approve.

As a side note, I have seen sloppy editors do this as well. People on editing sprees, retagging sprees or attempting to make spam edits, also sometimes use parts of the edited post as the Edit Summary. So it *can* be a sign of bad editing. But that's all it is - a sign. In the end, edits must be judged on their own merit.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree with this. Part of the merit of a suggested edit is the edit summary. I regularly reject edits when the edit summary is a blatant lie.

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough, though I can't remember having seen blatant lies in edit summaries myself. I guess if an editor is going to lie in the Edit Summary, there's likely to be problems with the edit itself too.

Comment: I see them rather often. "Improved formatting" when a big paragraph of text is added, for example. Sometimes that paragraph of text is actually additional information incorporated from the comments and therefore would be a legitimate edit, but with that edit summary, no one would ever know it was a legitimate edit, especially once the comments get flagged and deleted as obsolete.